# PDO execute() com ligações não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Versão PHP:** 5.6
**Framework:** Slim
**Motor de Pesquisa à bd:** PDO

Tenho a seguinte pesquisa à base de dados:

```
$cIndus = array("ex1", "ex2");
$query = "SELECT `nome_agr_corr` AS `brita`,
                        CASE
                        WHEN ? = 'usd' AND ? = 'externos' AND ? = 'toneladas'
                        THEN ROUND(`valor_ex_ton`,2)
                        WHEN ? = 'usd' AND ? = 'externos' AND ? = 'm3'
                        THEN ROUND(`valor_ex_ton` * `baridade`,2)
                        WHEN ? = 'usd' AND ? = 'internos' AND ? = 'toneladas'
                        THEN ROUND(`valor_in_ton`,2)
                        WHEN ? = 'usd' AND ? = 'internos' AND ? = 'm3'
                        THEN ROUND(`valor_in_ton` * `baridade`,2)

                        WHEN ? = 'aoa' AND ? = 'externos' AND ? = 'toneladas'
                        THEN TRIM(ROUND(`valor_ex_ton` * ?))+0
                        WHEN ? = 'aoa' AND ? = 'externos' AND ? = 'm3'
                        THEN TRIM(ROUND(`valor_ex_ton` * `baridade` * ?))+0
                        WHEN ? = 'aoa' AND ? = 'internos' AND ? = 'toneladas'
                        THEN TRIM(ROUND(`valor_in_ton` * ?))+0
                        WHEN ? = 'aoa' AND ? = 'internos' AND ? = 'm3'
                        THEN TRIM(ROUND(`valor_in_ton` * `baridade` * ?))+0
                        END AS `preco`
                  FROM `agregados`
                  LEFT JOIN `valorun_interno_ton`
                  ON `agr_id` = `agr_bar_id`
                  LEFT JOIN `valorun_externo_ton`
                  ON `agr_id` = `agr_bar_ton_id`
                  LEFT JOIN `baridades`
                  ON `agr_id` = `agregado_id`
                  WHERE `nome_agre` IN (?)
                  GROUP BY `nome_agr_corr`
                  ORDER BY `nome_agr_corr`
                 ";

        $rows = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $rows->execute([$tipoTabela, $destino, $unidade,
                        $tipoTabela, $destino, $unidade,
                        $tipoTabela, $destino, $unidade,
                        $tipoTabela, $destino, $unidade,

                        $tipoTabela, $destino, $unidade, $cambioDoDia,
                        $tipoTabela, $destino, $unidade, $cambioDoDia,
                        $tipoTabela, $destino, $unidade, $cambioDoDia,
                        $tipoTabela, $destino, $unidade, $cambioDoDia,

                        $cIndus
      ]);
```

Todas as variáveis são colocadas nas suas posições, julgo eu, pois, não dá nenhum erro. Aparece somente uma tabela em branco, quando deveria estar preenchida. O que estarei a fazer mal.
Tenho o mostrar erros activado: `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Testei com "colocadores" (placeholders) em vez de "?" e o resultado é o mesmo... nada!

```
$query = "SELECT `nome_agr_corr` AS `brita`,
                                 CASE
                                 WHEN ':tipoTabela' = 'usd' AND ':destino' = 'externos' AND ':unidade' = 'toneladas'
                                 THEN ROUND(`valor_ex_ton`,2)
                                 WHEN ':tipoTabela' = 'usd' AND ':destino' = 'externos' AND ':unidade' = 'm3'
                                 THEN ROUND(`valor_ex_ton` * `baridade`,2)
                                 WHEN ':tipoTabela' = 'usd' AND ':destino' = 'internos' AND ':unidade' = 'toneladas'
                                 THEN ROUND(`valor_in_ton`,2)
                                 WHEN ':tipoTabela' = 'usd' AND ':destino' = 'internos' AND ':unidade' = 'm3'
                                 THEN ROUND(`valor_in_ton` * `baridade`,2)

                                 WHEN ':tipoTabela' = 'aoa' AND ':destino' = 'externos' AND ':unidade' = 'toneladas'
                                 THEN TRIM(ROUND(`valor_ex_ton` * ':cambioDoDia'))+0
                                 WHEN ':tipoTabela' = 'aoa' AND ':destino' = 'externos' AND ':unidade' = 'm3'
                                 THEN TRIM(ROUND(`valor_ex_ton` * `baridade` * ':cambioDoDia'))+0
                                 WHEN ':tipoTabela' = 'aoa' AND ':destino' = 'internos' AND ':unidade' = 'toneladas'
                                 THEN TRIM(ROUND(`valor_in_ton` * ':cambioDoDia'))+0
                                 WHEN ':tipoTabela' = 'aoa' AND ':destino' = 'internos' AND ':unidade' = 'm3'
                                 THEN TRIM(ROUND(`valor_in_ton` * `baridade` *':cambioDoDia'))+0
                                 END AS `preco`
                           FROM `agregados`
                           LEFT JOIN `valorun_interno_ton`
                           ON `agr_id` = `agr_bar_id`
                           LEFT JOIN `valorun_externo_ton`
                           ON `agr_id` = `agr_bar_ton_id`
                           LEFT JOIN `baridades`
                           ON `agr_id` = `agregado_id`
                           WHERE `nome_agre` IN (':cindus')
                           GROUP BY `nome_agr_corr`
                           ORDER BY `nome_agr_corr`
                          ";

        $rows = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $rows->execute([':tipoTabela' => $tipoTabela,
                        ':destino'    => $destino,
                        ':unidade'    => $unidade,
                        ':cindus'     => $cIndus
        ]);
```

**NOTA:** Os valores das variáveis são parametros da função. (`public function getSQL_interno($cInd, $tipoTabela, $destino, $mesActual, $unidade)`) e uma variável global (`cIndus`).

Comment: Qual é a mensagem que deu nos dois casos?

Comment: Absolutamente nenhuma. Onde deveria aparecer um quadro com valores, aparece um quadro vazio.